# Setup NAS-initiated backup from PC independently of PC software

Tags: backup, nas

Can I make a NAS (e.g. WD cloud mirror) access the files on my PC and backup them *independently* from my PC, so that it acts like an autonomous "backup server"? In the meaning that the NAS pulls data on its own, but the PC itself has no means to get write access to NAS, even if the PC is infected with malware? It is meant for backup only, i.e. for regular use the PC may have (for convenience to check if it is working), but does not need to have read access to the NAS.

Comment: That's usually not how backup solutions work. Backup solutions require an agent installed on the PC you want to back up then the PC uploads the data to the NAS. But you want to do it backwards. In order to do that you would have to configure your PC to act as a file server itself then configure the NAS to connect to it then backup files. I don't think that NAS even has that capability. You would have to create your own Linux NAS and write a script to do what you want.

Comment: Most NAS devices run some form of Linux. My old Seagate Goflex NAS ran a version of ARM Linux. You could easily make PC folders shared, mount them on the NAS, and create scripts, cron jobs, etc, to do what you want.  My current home NAS is a Raspberry Pi 4 with a 2 TB drive attached, and it regularly backs its own system partition to an image file and then transfers that to a folder on my PC. You can do these things with FreeNAS, etc, as well.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Thanks. Only reason for this "backwards" (xR34P3Rx) approach ist immunity of the (Linux-)NAS against PC-malware, which - if capable of writing files there for backup - could easily also instruct the NAS to delete or overwrite with encryped files. Could you comment on the most secure way to share PC folders, it save to use PC "Network and sharing center" and on Linux side Samba/Nautilus/Konqueror/smbclient as detailed herehttps://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001636.htm, https://www.howtogeek.com/176471/how-to-share-files-between-windows-and-linux/
=> please post as answer :-)